# Red 5 server startup problem on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, startup, red5

My Red 5 installation went good on Windows 7 but I am unable to start it up. I am getting the following error on the console :

```
Root: C:/Program Files/Red5
Deploy type: bootstrap
Logback selector: org.red5.logging.LoggingContextSelector
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.red5.server.Bootstrap.bootStrap(Bootstrap.java:118)
    at org.red5.server.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/bridge/SLF4JBridgeHandler
    at org.red5.server.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
    ... 6 more
```

Any workarounds ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved !

Just use the zipped version of Red5 1.0 , the binaries are somewhat buggy.